# PHP login form failure

Tags: php, mysql

I am new to PHP and am having an issue with my login script which I have spent hours looking at and can't figure out where I am going wrong.

Whenever I try to login, I am greeted with the "Either the email address and password entered do not match those on file or you have not yet activated your account" statement as per my code below. The email address and password are stored in the database and were entered using my registration and activation script which are both working fine and also connect to my database via a MySQL connection script and also use the config script.

I have actually built this script based on a course that I have been taking which is now a little concerning!!

If anyone has any advice on where I am going wrong, I would be very grateful.

Many thanks in advance!!

```
 <?php # login.php


   include ('./includes1/headerregistration.html');
   require_once ('./includes1/config.php');
$page_title = 'Login';

if (isset($_POST['submitted'])) { // Check if the form has been submitted.
   require_once ('./mysql_connect.php');

   // Validate the email address.
   if (!empty($_POST['email'])) {
      $e = escape_data($_POST ['email']);
   } 

   else {
      echo '<p><font color="red"size="+1"> You forgot to enter your email address!
      </font></p>';
      $e = FALSE;
   }

   // Validate the password.
   if (!empty($_POST['pass'])) {
      $p = escape_data($_POST ['pass']);
   } 

   else {
      $p = FALSE;
      echo '<p><font color="red"size="+1"> You forgot to enter your password!
      </font></p>';
   } 
if ($e && $p) { // If everything's OK.
   // Query the database.
   $query = "SELECT id, first_name FROM Jobseekers WHERE (email='$e' AND pass=SHA('$p')) AND active IS NULL";
   $result = mysql_query ($query) or trigger_error("Query: $query\n <br />MySQL Error: " . mysql_error()); 

if (@mysql_num_rows ($result) == 1) { // A match was made.
      // Register the values & redirect.
      $row = mysql_fetch_array ($result,MYSQL_NUM);
      mysql_free_result($result);
      mysql_close();
      $_SESSION['first_name'] = $row[1];
      $_SESSION['id'] = $row[0];

      // Start defining the URL.
      $url = 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . dirname($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);

      // Check for a trailing slash.
      if ((substr($url, -1) == '/') OR(substr($url, -1) == '\\') ) {
        $url = substr ($url, 0, -1); // Chop off the slash.
      }
      // Add the page.
      $url .= '/indexregtest.php';
      ob_end_clean(); // Delete the buffer.
      header("Location: $url");
      exit(); // Quit the script. 
 } 
 else { // No match was made.
        echo '<p><font color="red"size="+1">Either the email address and password entered do not match those on file or you have not yet activated your account.</font></p>';
      }
   } 
   else {
      echo '<p><font color="red"size="+1">Please try again.</font></p>';
   }
   mysql_close();
} // End of SUBMIT conditional.
?>

<h1>Login</h1>
<p>Your browser must allow cookies in order to log in.</p>
<form action="login.php"method="post">
   <fieldset>
   <p><b>Email Address:</b> <input type="text" name="email" size="20" maxlength="40" value="<?php if (isset($_POST['email'])) echo $_POST['email']; ?>" /></p>
   <p><b>Password:</b> <input type="password" name="pass" size="20" maxlength="20" /></p>
   <div align="center"><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Login" /></div>
   <input type="hidden" name="submitted" value="TRUE" />
   </fieldset>
</form>

<?php
include ('./includes1/footerregistration.html');
?>
```

Comment: html `font` tags, and `mysql_*` library are deprecated.  Are you encrypting the data at all when they register? If so compare the encrypted values when checking.

Comment: @OP are you sure that your database is okey ? You may have duplicate entry

Comment: `AND active IS NULL`. Did you mean `AND active IS NOT NULL`?

Comment: Thanks julienhaversano, sorry to sound a little dull but as I said I am new to this... should I use mysqli instead? I am encrypting the password so do I need to add anything to the script?

Comment: Hi Shanoop, I have email set as unique in the database and there is no duplicate upon checking.

Comment: Sasha you are a gem!!! I just tried IS NOT NULL and it works!!! Thanks all so much for your help :-)

Comment: @user3316536, I quite don't understand how it can work. Because `AND active IS NULL` is not the main problem in your code.

Comment: I am not sure but it is working lol. I also changed the $result string as suggested.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$result = mysql_query ($query) or trigger_error("Query: $query\n <br />MySQL Error: " . mysql_error());
```

Don't do this. It's not a JavaScript. `or` and `and` operators always return strictly `true` or `false`.

```
$result = mysql_query($query);
if(!$result) trigger_error("Query: $query\n <br />MySQL Error: " . mysql_error());
else {...some code...}
```

Comment: Sorry, I was wrong. I forgot that `or` in PHP has lower priority than `=`. This `$var = somefunc(...) or somehandleerrorfunc(...)` will work.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know your databasefields, but in your query you are asking for rows, where the field "active" is set to null (..`AND active IS NULL`). Are you sure in active accounts is this field null?
Maybe check out how many rows you get with your query (`echo mysql_num_rows ($result)`) and check why it's not 1.

Comment: Your doubt about correctness of `AND active IS NULL` is very plausible. However, his main problem is not that. See my answer.